# Trying to create an array condition

Tags: php, arrays

I have a text field which the user can enter comma separated list and then php converts it to a drop select list however I want a condition that will show a text input field if only a single value is entered. I tried the code below but it is only returning the select box even with a single entry. How can I achieve this condition?

```
<?php $listval = explode(",",$vals);
if(is_array($listval)) { ?>

<select name="valuelist">
<?php 
    foreach($listval as $value) {
    echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
} ?>
</select>

<?php }else{ ?>

<input type="text" size="10" name="valuelist" value="<?php echo $vals; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Seperating by comma is not advisable thing why because in some cases the name also contains commas...

Comment: you should have a look at database normalization link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

explode will always return an array. So therefor is_array will always be true.
Change your if statement to this

```
if(sizeof($listval) > 1)
```

Comment: This worked well and is quite simple so it has been implemented. Thanks

Comment: Great! If this solution works for you, would you consider accepting my answer as being correct? You can click on the checkbox beside my answer to do so

Comment: So sorry. All this time I did not realise that I missed the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
<?php $listval = strpos(',',$vals)?explode(",",$vals):$vals;
if(is_array($listval)) { ?>

<select name="valuelist">
<?php 
    foreach($listval as $value) {
    echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
} ?>
</select>

<?php }else{ ?>

<input type="text" size="10" name="valuelist" value="<?php echo $vals; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the follwing code:

```
<?php $listval = explode(",",$vals);
if(count($listval) > 1) { ?>
<select name="valuelist">
<?php 
    foreach($listval as $value) {
    echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
} ?>
</select>

<?php } elseif(count($listval) == 1) { ?>

<input type="text" size="10" name="valuelist" value="<?php echo $vals; ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Kris indicated, you can check with,

```
     count($array)
```

or

```
     sizeof($array)


   <?php $listval = explode(",",$vals);
      $array_count = count($listval);
      if($array_count > 1) { ?>

      <select name="valuelist">
      <?php 
         foreach($listval as $value) {
           echo '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
       } ?>
       </select>

      <?php }else{ ?>

          <input type="text" size="10" name="valuelist" value="<?php echo $vals; ?>" />
      <?php } ?>
```